# Send Emails using Process Builder on weekdays only

Tags: process-builder

Our client is using salesforce professional edition and he wants us to setup process builders that will only send emails on weekdays only. Is this possible? Or the way only to this is to upgrade their salesforce subscription and use programmatic implementations?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use apex for above use case. But if your criteria for sending email is not complex and you want to stick with your existing process builder logic then you can schedule emails for Saturday and Sunday.

you will only need to add criteria

```
Weekday(Today()) == 7 || Weekday(Today()) == 1
```

in your existing process builder criteria and schedule your email action for 1 or 2 days of edited date.

But if your process builder is already very complex don't use above solution go with custom apex logic.

Answer (score 1):

Using process builder we can schedule the email. But for scheduling we have options in DAYS and HOURS only. We will not be able to put in weekday check using process builder.
You can easily achieve this using apex. You can use DateTime class methods to get the day from the given date.